# Unity messes up X-axis rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a very simple script that I wish to rotate something on the X-axis, and I'd expect the other two axes to stay put(they flip between 0 and 180), and only X to change.

Below you can see the code intended to do just that.

```cs
    public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void Start()
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
            Debug.Log($"start rotation: {transform.eulerAngles}");
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            float time = (Time.time - 1f) * 10f;
            if (time < 0f || time > 1f)
            {
                return;
            }
            Vector3 rotation = transform.eulerAngles;
            float x = Mathf.Lerp(170f, 0, time);
            rotation.x = x;
            transform.eulerAngles = rotation;
            Debug.Log($"rotation: {transform.eulerAngles}, x: {x}");
        }
    }
```

The output from the console.  You can clearly see that the rotation does not go from 170 to 0, but from 0 to 90 and then back to 0.

[image: result]

Now, I'm pretty sure this has something to do with quaternions and their identity, but not sure how can this be avoided

PS: The same idea but for Y and Z works just fine.

Comment: I brought this up in the comments but it would be more proper to bring it up here. Can you explain what you mean by "Z works just fine"? If I create a class similar to what is in the question here but use `z` instead of `x` and use `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(90,0,0);`, then I get a similar undesirable result.

Comment: You might also want to re-read the documentation on [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html), especially the part that says, "Do not set one of the eulerAngles axis separately (eg. `eulerAngles.x = 10;` ) since this will lead to drift and undesired rotations." and using `Vector3 rotation = transform.eulerAngles; rotation.x = 10; transform.eulerAngles = rotation;` is equivalent to the example.

Answer (score 1):

OP:

> I have a very simple script that I wish to rotate something on the X-axis, and I'd expect the other two axes to stay put(they flip between 0 and 180), and only X to change.

> You can clearly see that the rotation does not go from 170 to 0, but from 0 to 90 and then back to 0.  Now, I'm pretty sure this has something to do with quaternions

Well the real culprit is Euler angles.

If we take a look at your code:

```
Vector3 rotation = transform.eulerAngles;
float x = Mathf.Lerp(170f, 0, time);
rotation.x = x;
transform.eulerAngles = rotation;
Debug.Log($"rotation: {transform.eulerAngles}, x: {x}");
```

...we can see you are performing rotations via `transform.eulerAngles`.  The thing about 3D rotations is that you should avoid using Euler due to their limitations and problems (gimbal lock anyone) and use quaternions instead.  The latter is *the source of truth.*

Unity (my emphasis):

> When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. **Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned.** This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.

...which is exactly what is happening with your code.

Consider this:

[image]

Notice anything about the `23.5` and the `156.5`?

```
23.5 + 156.5 = 180
```

In other words both will lead to the same rotation as per *"there is more than one way to represent any given rotation"*.

An arguable simpler approach is:

```
public class RotateWithTime : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField,Tooltip("Rotation rate in degrees/second")] 
    private Vector3 rotationSpeed; // e.g. (30,0,0) for 30 deg/sec X-only

    private void Reset()
    {
        rotationSpeed = Vector3.zero;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var amount = rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Rotate(amount);
    }
}
```

And a version without `Vector3`s:

```
public class RotateWithTimeNoV3 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField,Tooltip("Rotation rate in degrees/second")] 
    private float rotationSpeedX; // e.g. 30 for 30 deg/sec X-only

    private void Reset()
    {
        rotationSpeedX = 0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var amount = rotationSpeedX * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Rotate(amount, 0f, 0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is actually not useful at all. I knew all this. I knew that they add up. But that is not my problem. I still need to change the individual axis. Your response changed the functionality of what I need to do. If I have another script that only changes the Y axis(which I actually do) this won't work.

Comment: @DanielTranca Why won't this work if you want to only rotate around the y axis? That is exactly what will happen if `rotationSpeed` is set to a vector of the form `(0,q,0)` where `q` is a non-zero value. This answer also answers your question as to why it's incorrect to expect "the other two axes to stay put...and only X to change." when using `Transform.eulerAngles`. It also provides a "very simple script that I wish to rotate something on the X-axis". So, overall it's a high quality answer.

Comment: I want to have 2 separate rotations, one on X one on Y on the exact same object at the exact same time.

Comment: @DanielTranca From the above comment it sounds like your question was really something like "for a given rotation Q and a euler angle representation E for a different rotation, how do I find the euler angle representation of Q which is most numerically similar to E" but that wasn't clear from the question. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55508/how-can-i-find-equivalent-euler-angles/55552) may be of interest, especially the "(α,β,γ)→(α+π,π−β,γ+π) leads to the same rotation." part

Comment: Note that α & α+π is z, β & π−β is x, and γ & γ+π is y due to the ZXY order that unity uses for euler angles and it is measured in radians, so it may be easier to read expressed in unity terms and degrees as "(x,y,z)→(180−x, y+180, z+180) leads to the same rotation"

Comment: @DanielTranca By the way, I can almost guarantee that you don't have a script that "only changes the Z axis" (according to transform.eulerAngles). Try setting the starting rotation to (x=90, y=0, z=0) and attempt to "only change the z axis" using the method in the question.  Anyway, if you would like to have help achieving your goal, it would help to include more information about that goal to avoid further [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/405359), **in a new question** to avoid this one from becoming a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/405359)

Comment: This is caused by the 3rd equivalence type on that math post because β≡0(mod π/2)

Comment: @DanielTranca 1) nonsense 2) don't go changing the desired outcome _after_ an answer has been posted

Comment: @DanielTranca _"I want to have 2 separate rotations, one on X one on Y on the exact same object at the exact same time."_ - please take note of _["Looks like <refer to original problem> is solved isn't it? As for <refer to "next" problem>, that would be a different question, consider posting it separately."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253829/585968)_

Comment: MickyD sorry mate, but you are wrong. If you look into my code I specifically used only the X axis of the vector. You used a Vector3. My problem didn't change, your answer provided a solution for a problem that I did not ask for. @Ruzihm is onto something though, but I'm not sure I fully understand, the math is a bit over my hear

Comment: @DanielTranca the question doesn't mention avoiding V3s (it does use a V3 so you'll understand how we missed that detail). I added an alternative version that uses zero V3s. Hopefully this helps. Consider adding a new question if not.

Comment: @DanielTranca sorry _you_ are wrong.  You also missed the point entirely

Comment: @Ruzihm you are correct. I finally understood the math, and I do have a script that only changes the Z axis and it does what you said it does. I can share the script, but it's integrated in a library and most of the functionality if rendered in other scripts. I also think you are right and I should post the question in a different thread with more precise direction on what I want to achieve and all the fixes that won't be helpful.

Comment: @MickyD your edit still doesn't solve the issue, just provides a different way to do something else. I'd like to delete this question and ask a new one that will be way more explicit

Comment: In order to ask the proper question next time. Here are the scripts mainly involved, and what I'm trying to achieve. [Abstract Axis](https://github.com/Fried-Synapse/FlowEnt/blob/main/Assets/FlowEnt/Scripts/Motions/Tween/Engine/Transforms/AbstractAxisMotion.cs) [Rotation](https://github.com/Fried-Synapse/FlowEnt/blob/main/Assets/FlowEnt/Scripts/Motions/Tween/Engine/Transforms/RotateAxisMotion.cs)

Comment: Agreed.  Feel free to post again as I suggested

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid this question becoming a chameleon question due to the lack of info in the initial question, I have asked a new one and will be closing this one. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70732202/how-to-properly-rotate-a-single-axis-while-not-touching-the-others)