# How to properly rotate a single axis while not touching the others

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script where I wish to rotate something on the X-axis, and I'd expect the other two axes to stay put and not be modified(they flip between 0 and 180), and only X to change.

Below you can see the code intended to do just that.

```cs
    public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void Start()
        {
            //this line is meant to show that I'm reseting the rotation before starting
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
            Debug.Log($"start rotation: {transform.eulerAngles}");
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            float time = (Time.time - 1f) * 10f;
            if (time < 0f || time > 1f)
            {
                return;
            }
            Vector3 rotation = transform.eulerAngles;
            float x = Mathf.Lerp(170f, 0, time);
            rotation.x = x;
            transform.eulerAngles = rotation;
            Debug.Log($"rotation: {transform.eulerAngles}, x: {x}");
        }
    }
```

The output from the console.  You can clearly see that the rotation does not go from 170 to 0, but from 0 to 90 and then back to 0.

[image: result]

Now, I'm pretty sure this has something to do with quaternions and their identity, but not sure how can this be avoided

PS: Before you answer please read this

1. I do not want to rotate the whole object by using a Vector. I only want to rotate one axis at a time.
2. I know that this is due to the fact that quaternions represent a rotation, and there are multiple ways to represent a rotation when converting into euler angles, but that doesn't help me, because I do only want to do one axis rotation and the others not to be modified. At all.
3. I'm actually trying to do this for the other 2 axes too.
4. The rotation has to be from one value to another during a specific period of time, rather than rotate a certain amount over an unspecified amount of time.
5. This script is not actually what I'm trying to achieve but a simplified version of my issue. If any of this is not that clear, check these 2 scripts, where I'm actually trying to achieve this. [Abstract Axis](https://github.com/Fried-Synapse/FlowEnt/blob/main/Assets/FlowEnt/Scripts/Motions/Tween/Engine/Transforms/AbstractAxisMotion.cs) [Rotate](https://github.com/Fried-Synapse/FlowEnt/blob/main/Assets/FlowEnt/Scripts/Motions/Tween/Engine/Transforms/RotateAxisMotion.cs)

Comment: Is there a unit test that shows some desired outcomes of this? It's still vague what the desired outcome would be, especially in cases where you have gimbal lock, or have other unrelated things modifying the rotation at the same time

Comment: Like if I start with 0,0,0 and tell it to go from x=0 to x=360, then halfway through some unrelated code sets it to 90, 180, 180, which unity will have t.ea read back as (for instance) 90, 0, 360. What is supposed to happen next frame (assume next x=181)? Is your code meant to set it back to 181, 180, 180, or change it to 181, 0, 360?

Comment: Hey, @Ruzihm thank you very much for your comments. That is a very good question. I do have a unity test but it doesn't cover all these cases yet. [Code](https://github.com/Fried-Synapse/FlowEnt/blob/main/Assets/FlowEnt%20Tests/Unit/Tests/Motions/Engine/TransformTweenTests.cs#L730). In terms of your question, a good one btw, I'd say 181, 0, 360. I don't really care what you do with the other axes and if your quaternion messes up the rotation. All that I care about is that my rotation doesn't change yours. Does that make sense?

Comment: What if it isn't unrelated? Suppose at 1/4 of the way through it's at 90, 0, 0, and y and z instances have been added to go from 180 to 360. I assume that they would need to set it to 90, 180, 180, which unity reads back as ( for instance) 90, 0, 360. On the next frame, x instance activates and has to set the ea. Does it set 90, 0, 360?  What does it set if the other two instances were cancelled/deleted immediately after they were made and changed the rotation on their first frame? Apologies for typos and early submits - phone posting

Comment: Correction: Does it set 91, 0, 360

Comment: I'd assume it would have to stick to what the script is saying. x goes from 0 to 360 and y and z got from 180 to 360, without unity trying to describe the rotation in a different way. I guess, what I'd really like, is, if unity can describe the same rotation in two euler angles, how do I force it to represent in the one that I like? Or, for example, can I check the quadrant and manually switch to the euler angles that I need?

Comment: it should do 91, 181, 181. Since all 3 axes are controller by my scripts and not someone else's, I'd like to keep the values I set. But since this is a library, I do not want to impose this restriction to anyone else's rotation

Answer (score 0):

I would store a `Vector3` where all 1-3 `TestScript` varieties can view and edit it, such that no `Transform` has more than one of these vector3 associated with it. This could be stored in a dictionary, for instance, where each Transform could be used as a key. There are other ways this could be done but that is out of scope. I'll call the value of this vector3 `cache` for the sake of simplicity.

You will also need a way for each script to determine which components of the euler angles are not controlled. This can be done in a manner similar to `cache` and how to implement is also out of scope for this question.

Have each `TestScript` update `cache` so that the vector component it controls is set to its current interpolation value. Then have each component assign that `cache` to the `eulerAngles`, or optionally, have only the final `TestScript` make that assignment.

> In terms of your question, a good one btw, I'd say 181, 0, 360. I don't really care what you do with the other axes and if your quaternion messes up the rotation.

Since you would want to have this internal state vector not override uncontrolled vector components in the event any outside change occurs, here's what you could do about that:

When the first `TestScript` variety in a frame executes, compare (using e.g. `Quaternion.Angle(a,b) < 0.00001f` so that it treats 540,0,0 the same as 180,0,0) the transform's current `rotation` with the quaternion produced by [`Quaternion.Euler(cache)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html). If the rotations are determined to be different, assign the uncontrolled components of the transform's `eulerAngles` to `cache` and then continue with the usual operation.

Pseudocode, underscore_case stuff is VERY pseudo:

```
Transform myTransform;
Vector3 startEulers = myTransform.eulerAngles;
Vector3 cache = get_cache(myTransform);

if (is_this_TestScript_first_to_go_this_frame())
{
    if (Quaternion.Angle(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(cache)) < 0.0001f)
    {
        if (is_x_uncontrolled(myTransform)) 
            cache.x = startEulers.x;
        if (is_y_uncontrolled(myTransform))
            cache.y = startEulers.y;
        if (is_z_uncontrolled(myTransform))
            cache.z = startEulers.z;
        set_cache(myTransform, cache);
    }
}

switch(my_axis)
{
case X:
    cache.x = get_current_interp_val();
    break;
case Y:
    cache.y = get_current_interp_val();
    break;
case Z:
    cache.z = get_current_interp_val();
    break;
default:
    throw exception;
}

myTransform.eulerAngles = cache;
```

This will get you started toward what you want.

Comment: it's a good start, but not what I need. This still controls the other two axes. Considering this is done in a library, that might not be feasible. I do need a complete separation of concern between the axis.

Comment: That's impossible using eulerangles, good luck!

Comment: Also, once again you've added conditions onto your question to invalidate an already written answer - your comments to the first question outright say that if instances of answer code code only modify x and y, and then unity AND NOTHING ELSE changes the Z component, then a valid answer must IGNORE the change to the Z component, AKA overwrite it. It is plain as day that you simply do not know what you want from an answer.

Comment: *discard not ignore the change to the Z component might be more accurate

Comment: You're right though. I didn't change the conditions of the questions. I did mention that this is used in a library, and that's why I can't touch/create a system for the other axes. You are right in the sense that this can't be done because of how unity interprets quaternions.  Shame. I managed to achieve what I wanted, sort of, using a different approach (transform.Rotate(Vector3))

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved due to how Unity interprets quaternions. If you want to do this you might want to go a different route. transform.Rotate(Vector3) did the trick for me. This is not the solution I'm using but this is how the script I originally posted would have to be modified to achieve the same thing.

```cs
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float lastX;
    private void Start()
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
        lastX = transform.eulerAngles.x;
        Debug.Log($"start rotation: {transform.eulerAngles}");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float time = Time.time - 1f;
        if (time < 0 || time > 1f)
        {
            return;
        }
        float x = Mathf.Lerp(0f, -170f, time);
        Vector3 rotation = new Vector3(x - lastX, 0f, 0f);
        lastX = x;
        transform.Rotate(rotation);
        Debug.Log($"rotation: {transform.eulerAngles}, x: {x}");
    }
}
```